# Firebase one to many relationship with search

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

im doing a basic react native application with firebase as backend, and its my first time with NoSQL database and im a little confused about how to organize the database.

I want a simple one-to-many bidirectional, i will do a lot of search with the "foreign key".

In common SQL the thing that i want is this:

```
+-------------+          +---------+
+ association +          + country +
+-------------+          +---------+
+ id          +          + id      +
+ name        +          + name    +
+ address     +          +---------+           
+ country_id  +          
+-------------+
```

I was thinking structure the firebase database like this:

```
/ : {
    associations: {
      Germany: {
        uuidAssociation1: {
          "name": "association1",
          "address": "address association1"
        }
      },
      France: {
        uuidAssociation2: {
          "name": "association2",
          "address": "address association2"
        },
        uuidAssociation3: {
          "name": "association3",
          "address": "address association3"
        }
      },      
    }
}
```

What u think about it? its a good idea? Maybe little scalable?

Comment: In NoSQL you often expand/modify your data model for the use-cases of our app. This makes it hard to say anything useful on a NoSQL data model without knowing the use-cases. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thank you Frank, i will see the two resources that you give me